# Метод класса или хелпер-функция?

Tags: ооп, typescript, cleancode, clean-architecture

По какому принципу можно определить, каким образом выносить кусок кода? Хелпер или метод?

Например есть класс для обработки Http-запросов.

```typescript
class HttpClient {
  // ... rest get, post, patch, etc methods
  public transformResponse<T>(response: Response, type: string): T {
    switch (type) {
      case 'json': {
        return response.json();
      }

      case 'text': {
        return response.text();
      }
      
      case 'blob': {
        return response.blob();
      }

      default: {
        return response.json();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

как видно из примера, метод `transformResponse` преобразует сырой ответ от сервера (FetchApi) в какой-то конкретный тип данных, в зависимости от агрумента `type`

Меня смущает, что хоть и этот процесс действительно по смыслу относится к работе `HttpClient`, но тем не менее, является некой дополнительной логикой, которая должна быть вынесена в обычную `helper`-функцию. Как минимум потому что, нет абсолюнтно никакого смысла содержать ее в классе, т.к. она не ссылается ни на какой `this`, по сути не требуя никакого контекста выполнения. Однако и сказать, что эта функция будет выполняться где-то вне класса я тоже не могу.

Возможно стоит ее вообще вынести в декоратор для каждого метода `http`-запроса?

Comment: Я всегда предпочитаю свободные функции. Классы уже достаточно сложны, если что-то можно уборать из класса не нарушая требований, это имеет смысл сделать.

Comment: А есть ли какие-то формальные требования к методам класса?

Comment: Не ссылается на `this` - ну это же статический метод класса, получается. Вполне нормально такое держать в классе, если это относится к классу.

Comment: "Требвания" - требования к коду: что он делает? Как быстро? Сколько нужно ресурсов для вычислений? Если вы можете убрать метод в функцию с сохранением требований, это имеет смысл сделать. Если вы написали метод, он попадает в интерфейс класса (даже если он приватный, его видит компилятор). Ему там место? Может пусть живёт в реализации и не замусоривает API?